# Problem with testing method with actingAs

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I have this code:

```
/**  @test */
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    // $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $response = $this->actingAs(User::find(1))->json('POST', '/store/ad', [
                'title' => 'Hello World',
                'city' => 1,
                'phone' => '666555555',
                'description' => 'fasd asd as d asd as d asd as d asd as d asd as d asd as da sd asd',
                'user_id' => 1
    ]);

    $response
        ->assertStatus(201)
        ->assertJson([
            'created' => true,
        ]);
}
```

Unfortunatly at this moment I have a first problem. It couldn't see users table.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1
>   no such table: users (SQL: select * from "users" where "users"."id" =
>   1 limit 1)

I'm looking how I can solve my problem and I found that I must using **DatabaseMigrations**. So I add that

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
//...
}
```

But now I have new problem.

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::actingAs() must implement
>   interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given

So I implement that

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    use Authenticatable;
//...
}
```

It's generated new error:

> Tests\Feature\ExampleTest cannot use
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable - it is not a trait

How can I solve my problem? How can I testing that?

### @Edit

I found problem but I don't know why it doesn't work. I have this rule to valdiate city

```
'city' => 'required|integer|exists:cities,id'
```

Problem is the last rule: exists:cities,id. I tryed different id exist cities and nothing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `DatabaseMigrations` trait will reset the database after each test, so there is no user in the database when the test is run.

That means that you are currently passing `null` in the following line:

```
$this->actingAs(User::find(1))
```

You have to create a user first using the `factory` helper:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
```

The following should solve your problem:

1 - Remove the following:

```
use Authenticatable;
```

Not sure why you even added this, the exception clearly states that the argument passed to `$this->actingAs()` has to implement the `Authenticatable` interface and not the current class.

2 - Change your test to something like this:

```
/**  @test */
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->actingAs(factory(User::class)->create())
        ->json('POST', '/store/ad', [
            'title' => 'Hello World',
            'city' => 1,
            'phone' => '666555555',
            'description' => 'fasd asd as d asd as d asd as d asd as d asd as d asd as da sd asd',
            'user_id' => 1
        ])
        ->assertStatus(201)
        ->assertJson(['created' => true]);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are doing on this route, so I cannot tell you why you are receiving this status code, but it is probably related to validation, try adding `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` at the start of your test, and check the error.

Comment: I found the problem but I don't know how solve it. I show it on my post

Comment: @Kowal8856 It is the same error as the user, the database is empty, there is no city, you have to create a city first for your test.